# simple js todo app with firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a todo app which will take my input and save it to database with the reference of current date so on the same day if I write something it will save to it and on the next day it will new child in databade and then save data on to it.
I don't know how the date function will work.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, just set the value of the child to the ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, and that will write the server unix time on that child

```
ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```